# Exchange a key with one of its values--python dictionary----another question

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following example, I have seen the execution flow of the piece of code, and I know it has a problem thus I cannot get the desired result from the code. However, I have tried many ways and still do not know, how can I get the desired result.

Code:

```
dict1 = {10: [22], 40: [50, 20, 60]}
new_dict = {}
for k, v in dict1.items():
    for each_v in v:
        if each_v < k:
            v.remove(each_v)
            # temp_v = v.copy()
            # temp_v.remove(each_v)
            new_dict[each_v] = [k] + v
            # print(temp_v)
            # print(v)
    else:
        new_dict[k] = v
print(new_dict)
```

Current output:

```
{10: [22], 20: [40, 50, 60], 40: [50, 60]}
```

Desired output:

```
{10: [22], 20: [40, 50, 60]}
*keep the original order*
```

What I only want, is to exchange the `key` and one of its `value`s **IF** the `key` is **bigger** than this `value`. I do not want to add more item to the dictionary. Also

If any of you has a hint, please do comment, thanks in advance!

Comment: what if multiple values are smaller than the key?

Comment: You shouldn't modify a list while you're iterating over it.

Comment: @Chris_Rands good question, then I pick up the smallest one

Comment: So you should use `if min(v) < k:` instead of looping over `v`.

Comment: @Chris_Rands, actually, my next step is to order the values inside of each 'value' list, maybe I should also consider to involve this requirement at this step

Comment: After you sort the list you can just do `if v[0] < k:` and swap them.

Comment: @Barmar, oh, this is a good idea, I forgot this, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach: iterate over a copy of all key, value pairs. If a values list has a value that is smaller than the key, we delete the key. Then we replace the smallest value in the list with the key, and use that value as the new key.

```
dict1 = {10: [22], 40: [50, 20, 60]}
for k, v in list(dict1.items()): # using list() to copy the dict's items
                                 # since we are going to delete a key
    min_v = min(v)
    if min_v < k:
        del dict1[k]
        min_v_index = v.index(min_v)
        v[min_v_index] = k
        dict1[min_v] = sorted(v)

print(dict1)
```

outputs

```
{10: [22], 20: [40, 50, 60]}
```

**A CAVEAT**

you **will** have a problem if a candidate key is already a key in the original dict. Consider having `{10: [22], 25: [10]}`. This will attempt to create a dictionary with duplicated `10` keys. The above code will output `{10: [25]}`.

The solution is to check if the new key is already present in the original dict, and if it does, just append the value to that key's list, then sort it. I will leave the implementation as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: @Melina I added an edge case as a caveat. Make sure you understand it as it may lead to unexpected output